# Integral Convolution of $e^{-|x|} \ast ax \chi_{[-c,c]}(x)$

Tags: real-analysis

For $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and $c \geq 0$, convolution of $f(x)=e^{-|x|}$ and $g(x)=ax\chi_{[-c,c]}(x)$

$$e^{-|x|} \ast (ax \chi_{[-c,c]}(x))=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-|y|}a(x-y)\chi_{[-c,c]}(x-y)dy$$

What I am thinking is to use the boundary of characteristic function (-c,c) then to separate the integral from -c to 0 and c to 0, but I don't know what would be with characteristic function?

Comment: The characteristic function just takes the value $1$ inside the set and $0$ outside, so if you put the $x-y$ in the exp, you can write the convolution as $a\int_{-c}^ce^{-|x-y|}ydy$.

Comment: @charlestoncrabb and what happened with a(x-y)... i see only $ay$?

Comment: Make the change of variables $y\mapsto x-y$

Comment: @charlestoncrabb thanks a lot

Comment: @charlestoncrabb then would integral be $a (\int_{-c}^{0}e^{-x-y}(-y) dy + \int_{0}^{c} e^{-x+y}ydy)$?

Comment: You need to split the integral at $x$ since $y=x$ is where $x-y$ switches sign. I'll spell it out in an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition of convolution and characteristic function, we can write (for clarity I will omit the constant $a$):
$$\left(e^{-|y|}*y\chi_{[-c,c]}(y)\right)(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-|x-y|}y\chi_{[-c,c]}dy=\int_{-c}^cye^{-|x-y|}dy.$$

At this point because of the absolute value, there are three cases to consider: $x<-c,-c\leq x\leq c$ and $x>c$.

1. $x<-c$:
   $$\int_{-c}^cye^{-|x-y|}dy=\int_{-c}^cye^{x-y}dy=\cdots \ (IBP),$$
2. $-c\leq x\leq c$:
   $$\int_{-c}^cye^{-|x-y|}dy=\int_{-c}^xye^{y-x}dy+\int_{x}^cye^{x-y}dy=\cdots \ (IBP),$$
3. $x>c$:
   $$\int_{-c}^cye^{-|x-y|}dy=\int_{-c}^cye^{y-x}dy=\cdots \ (IBP)$$

   Remember that this convolution is a *new* function of $x$, so each integral will of course depend on $x$, $c$, etc., and so the integrals in 1.-3. therefore give a piecewise-defined function.